# Scheduling SQL query in SSMS for reports to be sent by email

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried this particular query format to execute reports to be sent by email using SSMS, but it seems like it does not work well.
Could any experts help me on this?

Below given is the code.

```
declare @body1 varchar(4000)
declare @query varchar(2048)

set @body1 = 'Sample Email from SQL server ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR( 20 ), GETDATE(), 113 ) + 
' '

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name='Reporting',
    @recipients='ket@gmail.com',
    @subject = 'Test',
    @body = @body1,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query = ''Declare @Top  int = null       --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12
Declare @Nest varchar(25) =''  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,Path,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,PARENT_ID,Lvl,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(PROBLEM_TYPE_ID as varchar(500))
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,PARENT_ID
           ,Lvl=14
           ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME 
     From   problem_type 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(PARENT_ID,-1) else PROBLEM_TYPE_ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME)) as varchar(500))
           ,Path = cast(concat(cteHB.Path,'.',cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
           ,cteCD.PARENT_ID,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME  
     From   problem_type cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.PARENT_ID = cteHB.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID)
    ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
    ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID )
    ,cteFinalHier as (
        Select B.R1  
              ,C.R2
              ,A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
              ,A.PARENT_ID
              ,A.Lvl
              ,PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
              ,A.Seq                                      -- < Included for Illustration
              ,A.Path                                     -- < Included for Illustration
         From cteHB A
         Join cteR1 B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
         Join cteR2 C on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID
    )
Select A.Job_ticket_id as 'No.'
,A.Report_Date as 'Open Date'
      --,[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      --,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] =B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME
      ,concat (C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,'-',B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME) as 'Request Type'

      ,DATEDIFF(DAY,a.LAST_UPDATED,getdate()) as 'Days since Update'

      --,a.STATUS_TYPE_ID AS 'Status ID'

      ,STATUS_TYPE.STATUS_TYPE_NAME as 'Ticket Status'

      ,PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME as'Priority'

      --,A.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID
     ,isnull(t.lAST_NAME,'') + ' ' +isnull(T.FIRST_NAME,'') [Assigned Tech]
      ,TECH_GROUP.NAME as 'Tech Group'

  ------------------------------JOINS--------------------------------------------------                                                                                 
 From  JOB_TICKET A
 Join  cteFinalHier B on A.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID=B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID

 INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[PRIORITY_TYPE] ON A.[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID] = [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID]

 INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[STATUS_TYPE] ON A.[STATUS_TYPE_ID] = [STATUS_TYPE].[STATUS_TYPE_ID]

  inner join [SWHD01].[dbo].TECH_GROUP_LEVEL on A.TECH_GROUP_LEVEL_ID=TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.ID

 join TECH_GROUP on TECH_GROUP.ID= TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.tech_group_id

 LEFT JOIN TECH T on T.CLIENT_ID = A.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID

 Cross Apply (Select Top 1 * from cteFinalHier Where B.R1 between R1 and R2 and Lvl=1) C

 -------------Tickets for the Last 6 months---------------------------------------------------

 where datediff(month, A.REPORT_DATE, getdate()) <= 6


and a.STATUS_TYPE_ID <> 3
and NAME like '%NOC%'
and LEVEL_NUMBER ='2'
and DATEDIFF(DAY,a.LAST_UPDATED,getdate()) <> 0
and C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME not like 'Problem Management'
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Group By C.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,a.JOB_TICKET_ID,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_NAME,B.PROBLEM_TYPE_ID, a.REPORT_DATE,a.CLOSE_DATE,SWHD01.dbo.PRIORITY_TYPE.PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME,a.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE,B.R1,a.LAST_UPDATED,a.STATUS_TYPE_ID,TECH_GROUP_LEVEL.LEVEL_NUMBER,TECH_GROUP.NAME,STATUS_TYPE.STATUS_TYPE_NAME,A.ASSIGNED_TECH_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME
 Order By 'Days since Update' desc;

 exec (@query);

    @exclude_query_output = 1,
    @append_query_error = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'qry.csv',
    @query_result_no_padding = 1
```

I get the below error when i execute this query:

```
Msg 14625, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 280 [Batch Start Line 0]
Parameter @attach_query_result_as_file cannot be 1 (true) when no value is specified for parameter @query. A query must be specified to attach the results of the query.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Looks like `@query` is never redefined after `@query = ''`.

Comment: okay. what are the changes I can make for this to run smoothly? @mrogers

Comment: That is quite a query.  Have you considered/would you be able to use SSRS?  In addition to being able to create an attractive format for your output, you'd be able to schedule the email of the results in any number of ways, including to a mailing list based on a query.

Comment: But to answer your question, it -looks- as if your problem is that that enormous query of yours isn't actually a string.  You start it with  ' ', and it ends there.  You need to encase it with single quotes and make sure any single quote within it is doubled.

Answer (score 0):

When ever we declare varchar type data type we must assign blank values to them initially so that assignation will not fail. 
Few things you need to look at your code.

1. Parameter @query is having blank value so what you want execute from exec(@query) statement.
2. After exec(@query) you put ; that will terminate this statement so what you want to do with below variables

   @exclude_query_output = 1,
       @append_query_error = 1,
       @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
       @query_attachment_filename = 'qry.csv',
       @query_result_no_padding = 1